# Is there any trick to finding $\int_0^\pi [4 \cos (6x) + \cos(7x)] \cos(nx) dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to find
$$\int_0^\pi [4 \cos (6x) + \cos(7x)] \cos(nx) dx.$$
for $n \ge 8$. If the integral went from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, the integral would be zero by orthogonality. But alas it starts at $0$.

Is there any way to evaluate this quickly, and avoid doing product - to -sum formulas?

Comment: @Moo Sorry, my mistake. I was taking integrals from $-\frac\pi2$ to $\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$2\int_0^\pi [4\cos(6x)+\cos(7x)]\cos(nx)\, dx = \int_{-\pi}^\pi [4\cos(6x)+\cos(7x)]\cos(nx)\, dx =0$$
by exploiting that $\cos$ is even and orthogonality as you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for